# Sin(x): surjective and non-surjective with different codomain?

Tags: functions, trigonometry

Statement that $\operatorname{sin}(x)$ not surjective with codomain $\mathbb R$ and surjective with codomain $[-1,1]$ found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijection,_injection_and_surjection#Non-injective_and_non-surjective):

1. Non-surjective: $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}: x\mapsto\operatorname{sin}(x)$
2. Surjective: $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow[-1,1]: x\mapsto\operatorname{sin}(x)$

where the image $Im(f)=[-1,1]$ in both cases and the codomain is $\mathbb R$ and $[-1,1]$ for the case 1 and case 2, respectively. In the second case, $\forall x\in\mathbb R : \operatorname{sin}(x)\in [-1,1]$ where the codomain equals the image of $f$. Surjection means that the image of the function equals to the codomain.

**Why is sin not surjection with one codomain and surjective with other codomain?**

Comment: Every function is a surjection onto its image! This is the situation in 2.

Comment: @BrianO please preview the wikipedia link in the question, very first sentence where $\mathbb R\rightarrow\mathbb R : x\mapsto \operatorname{sin}(x)$ is claimed to be non-injective and non-surjective. Can you clarify your statement?

Comment: sin is a surjection if the codomain is $[0,1]$, but it is not a surjection if the codomain is $\mathbb R$

Comment: I don't have to: $\sin$ is not a surjection onto $\Bbb R$, obviously.  $\sin$ **is** a surjection onto $[-1, 1]$. Being a surjection is *with respect to a codomain*. You can't just say "$f$ is a surjection" if it's unclear what codomain you're talking about. It's like saying "John is taller", with no mention of anyone or anything else — taller than whom? or what?

Comment: This question is confusing; you seem to be discussing two cases (where $\sin$ is a map to $\mathbb R$ or $[0,1]$), but not clearly distinguishing between them in the question.

Comment: @MiloBrandt if you stricktly follow the statement *"surjection means that the image of the function equals to the codomain"*, why is $f(x)=sin(x)$ surjection from $\mathbb R \rightarrow [-1,1]$? I find this confusing.

Comment: Because $[-1, 1] = [-1, 1]$. What could be confusing about that? The codomain of $\sin\colon \Bbb R\to [-1, 1]$ is $[-1, 1]$, which equals the image of $\sin$  $= \sin(\Bbb R) = [-1,1]$. The codomain of $\sin\colon \Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ is $\Bbb R$. 1. and 2. are $\sin$ **with respect to different codomains**. They're different things. The *graph* of the two functions is, strictly speaking, the same: it's the same set of ordered pairs. But 1. and 2. draw a further distinction.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The functions $\operatorname{sin}:\mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R$ and $\operatorname{sin}: \mathbb R\rightarrow [-1,1]$ are **two different functions**. In mathematics, a function is usually defined as the collection of the following data:

- Specifying the domain X (a set)
- Specifying the codomain Y (a set)
- A [relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_relation) on $X\times Y$ [satisfying certain properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(mathematics)#Definition)

and so the mathematical function can be understood as an ordered triple set $\{X,Y,R\}$ where $R$ is the relation such as $X\times Y$. The usual notation is $f:X\to Y$.

In this strict sense, the string *''sin''* can represent infinitely many different functions, depending on the choice of domain and codomain. Some of them are surjective, injective, bijective, or none if that. For example, $\sin: [0,1]\to\Bbb R$ is injective but not surjective, $\sin: \Bbb R\to [-1,1]$ is surjective and not injective, $\sin: [-\pi/2,\pi/2]\to [-1,1]$ is bijective and so on.

However, that's not the whole story. In physics and engineering, one often ignores the specification of domain or/and codomain and assumes that it is understood from the context. In this sense, ''$\sin x$'' is an assignment that to a real number $x$ assigns $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} (-1)^{i}\frac{x^{2i+1}}{(2i+1)!}$. Here you don't care about domains and codomains. This is often good enough for practical considerations. But from the formal viewpoint, it doesn't make sense to ask whether this ''function'' $\sin$ is surjective, if you don't specify the domain and codomain.

Comment: +1 I added your key notice from your comment and tried to make things more explicit -- I read somewhere that set-theoretically there was someone about 1921 who differentiated the mathematical function as a triplet set from other functions. Feel free to correct my writing, thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

$f(x)=\sin(x)$ is not a surjection from $\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$

$f(x)=\sin(x)$ **is** a surjection from $\Bbb R\to [-1,1]$

The wiki page tells you that in the case of $\Bbb R\to [-1,1]$ that $\sin(x)$ **is** a surjection but **is not** an injection.  It is a surjection because every possible output has a preimage.  Suppose $y\in [-1,1]$.  Then for $x=\arcsin (y)\in\Bbb R$ you have $f(x)=\sin(\arcsin(y))=y$.

The wiki page also tells you that in the case of $\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ that $\sin(x)$ **is not** a surjection and **is not** an injection.  It is not a surjection because there exists no preimage for, say, the point $2$ in the codomain.  There is no real value of $x$ such that $\sin(x)=2$.

Neither case is an injection because you can have multiple $x$ values which map to the same output, for example $\sin(\pi)=\sin(3\pi)$

Comment: If you stricktly follow the statement *"surjection means that the image of the function equals to the codomain"*, why is $f(x)=sin(x)$ surjection from $\mathbb R \rightarrow [-1,1]$? You see that $Im(f)=[-1,1]$ and the codomain equals $[-1,1]$ so they are equal so contradiction somewhere? I find this confusing.

Comment: @hhh Maybe the confusion is here: these two functions $\sin: \Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ and $\sin: \Bbb R\to [-1,1]$ are **different functions**. A function is defined by two sets $A,B$ and certain relation on $A\times B$. Codomain is a part of the specification of the function, not its property.

Comment: @PeterFranek good point +1. What is the description about sin? Can it be explained with the concepts such as totality of function, partial functions, partial bijection and such terms? I added your point to a community wiki answer and I wanna understand the nature of functions such as sin deeper: the surjectivity and injectivity change with different codomain, interesting.

Comment: @hhh I tried to explain it in an answer